# The best particle of C# that is used to instead a template class which have a template base type in C++?

Tags: c#, c++

I want to ask a question about C#, let me give you an example.
this is a a simple example, i have a IVehicle interface, it have a Name property. and then, there are a Car class and a MotorBicycle class, they are implement IVehicle too. 
   one day, there is a vehicle factory which is named 'RedFlag', all of thire products have a flag on it. so there is a IFlagVehicle interface, it has a FlagColor property. if thire products are car and motorbicycle, so we need another two class: FlagCar and FlagMotorBicycle. 
   the demo codes in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    #region Example
    public interface IVehicle
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    #region Can't Changed This Region
    public class Car : IVehicle
    {
        public string Name => "Car";
    }

    public class MotorBicycle : IVehicle
    {
        public string Name => "MotorBicycle";
    }
    #endregion

    #region User Code
    public interface IFlagVehicle : IVehicle
    {
        string FlagColor { get; }
    }

    public class FlagCar : 
        Car,
        IFlagVehicle
    {
        public string FlagColor => "Red";
    }

    public class FlagMotorBicycle :
        MotorBicycle,
        IFlagVehicle
    {
        public string FlagColor => "Red";
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

in this code, we can see, we must implement FlagColor property in two classes, and they are same in a lot of time.
    but in C++, we can use a speicial template class, it use a template parameter as its BaseType, like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace  std;

class IVehicle
{
public:
    virtual string GetName() = 0;
};

class Car : public IVehicle
{
public:
    virtual string GetName() override
    {
        return "Car";
    }
};

class MotorBicycle : public IVehicle
{
public:
    virtual string GetName() override
    {
        return "MotorBicycle";
    }
};

class IFlagVechile 
{
public:
    virtual string GetFlagColor() = 0;
};

template < typename TBaseType >
class TFlagVechicle :
    public TBaseType,
    public IFlagVechile
{
public:
    virtual string GetFlagColor() override
    {
        return "Red";
    }
};

class FlagCar : public TFlagVechicle<Car>
{
};

class FlagMotorBicycle : public TFlagVechicle<MotorBicycle>
{
};


int main()
{
    FlagMotorBicycle fmb;
    cout << fmb.GetFlagColor() << " " << fmb.GetName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

int this case, we can implement the GetFlagColor function in the same place for common implement of these classes.
   so, i want to kown, is there any similar methods in C#? or I must change this design. if I must change this hierarchy, which is the best particle for this requirement in C#?
   thank you!

Comment: Which version of C#? Answers may be dependend on version, because you'll have different options with more recent versions of c#/.Net.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you might want [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: @Fildor, thanks for your reply, i use .net framework 4.5.2.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thanks for your reply, common generics of C# can't fix my questions.because i can't use a Generic Parameter as a BaseType.

Answer (score 0):

One of challenges here is that the C++ template inherits from two classes which is not possible in C# (you can only implement multiple interfaces but not inherit multiple classes).

Note however that in OO languages, one should favor delegation over inheritance. In fact,  delegating members between objects gives more flexibility, e.g. some members can be omitted, some members can be implemented conditionally etc.

One of options for you here then is **the delegation**, from the template to the private member the template creates for its own needs. It comes with a price of an additional constraint over the type that can be used as a template argument - the template has to create an instance and this can be constrained with the `new` constraint.

Note that the template delegates the `IVehicle` interface to the argument but it provides the implementation of the `IFlagVehicle` on its own.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FlagMotorBicycle fmb = new FlagMotorBicycle();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", fmb.FlagColor, fmb.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}

public interface IVehicle
{
    string Name { get; }
};

public class Car : IVehicle
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Car()
    {
        this.Name = "Car";
    }
};

public class MotorBicycle : IVehicle
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public MotorBicycle()
    {
        this.Name = "Bicycle";
    }
};

public interface IFlagVechile
{
    string FlagColor { get; }
};

public class TFlagVechicle<T> :
    IVehicle, IFlagVechile
    where T : class, IVehicle, new()
{
    private T t;

    public TFlagVechicle()
    {
        this.t = new T();
        this.FlagColor = "Red";
    }

    public string FlagColor { get; private set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return t.Name;
        }
    }
};

public class FlagCar : TFlagVechicle<Car>
{
};

public class FlagMotorBicycle : TFlagVechicle<MotorBicycle>
{
};
```